# What does $2 \mid 4$, $a\mid b,$ and $b\mid c$ mean in the solution given in my textbook?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am having trouble in understanding the solution given in my textbook of the following question:

> **Question**: $A$ relation $R$ defined on the set of integers by $R=\{(a, b): a$
> divides $b\}$ is
>
> (a) reflexive (b) symmetric (c) transitive (d) equivalence.
>
> **Solution**: $R$ is not *reflexive* since $(0,0) \not \subset R,$ as $0$ does not divide $0 .$
>
> $R$ is not *symmetric* since $2 \mid 4,$ but $4+2.$
>
> $R$ is *transitive* since $a\mid b,$ $ b\mid c \Rightarrow b=a n, c=bm,$ $ n, m \in
>  Z$
>
> $\Rightarrow c=a(n m) \quad(n m \in Z)$
>
> $\Rightarrow a \mid c$
>
> $\therefore \quad R$ is neither reflexive nor symmetric but it is
> transitive.
>
> $\therefore \quad R$ is not an equivalence relation.
>
> Hence (c) is correct answer.

I am not able to understand anything after and including the second line i.e. $R$ is not *symmetric* …. Specifically I am having trouble in understanding what does $2 \mid 4$, $a\mid b,$ and $b\mid c$ mean.

If $a\mid$ b mean "$b$ is divisible by $a$" then I am having trouble in undersding the whole second line i.e. "$R$ is not *symmetric* since $2 \mid 4,$ but $4+2.$." What does "$4+2$" have to do anything with the question?

Comment: $a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: “... but $4 +2$” should actually be “... but $4\not \mid 2.$”

Comment: @player3236 You’ve got it backwards. $a\mid b$ means $a$ is a divisor of $b,$ not $a$ is divisible by $b.$

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews it is written $4+2$ in the book! So it is a typo, maybe.

Comment: Since the usual definition of $a\mid b$ is that there is an integer $k$ with $ak=b$, it is debatable whether $0\mid 0$ holds or not. Sure, $k$ is not unique in this case, but the existence is clear.

Comment: The "+"-sign is probably meant as the similar sign "does not divide"

Comment: @Peter the relation is "$a$ divides $b$" not $a \mid b$

Comment: $a\mid b$ is nothing else than "$a$ divides $b$". It is also used in the solution.

Comment: The phrase $a$ divides $b$ is ambiguous for $(a,b)=(0,0)$ whether you like it or not. It depends on the definition of "divides" which is not given in your formulation of the question. The interpretation which others have made is quite a natural one. You can claim that "divides" means what you say it means for the purpose of the question, but I don't think that you can assume that this meaning is obvious without stating it explicitly. It is simply that usage differs in different contexts.

Comment: @ Mark Benne So is there any difference in $a \mid b$ and "$b$  is divisible by $a$", if I am using all the terms in their normal sense, in that sense where $0$ is not divisible by $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Well $a\mid b$ means there exists an integer $c$ such that $ac=b$.

1. Reflexive: $0\mid 0$ with arbitrary $c$.
2. Not symmetric, since $2\mid 4$ but not $4\mid 2$.
3. Transitive
4. No equivalence relation because of 2.

Comment: The relation is not reflexive since $0$ is not divisible by $0$. The relation is $a $ divides $b$ not $a \mid b$.

Comment: (+1) I agree that $0\mid 0$ holds

Comment: $0$ is the largest element in this order, every element divides $0$.

Comment: @ Peter I agree with that to. But $0$ is not divisible by $0$. So the relation is not reflexive.

Comment: "$a$ divides $b$" is equivalent to "$b$ is divisible by $a$" , UNLESS $a=b=0$ . In fact we cannot divide $0$ by $0$ , nevertheless "$0$ divides $0$" holds. And this is the formulation in the exercise.